# Как отменить усиление(изменение) цвета в местах пересечений двух полупрозрачных div

Tags: html, css, opacity

Есть куча блоков, поверх которых рисуются `div` c эффектами полупрозрачности(`background-color` + `opacity` либо `backdrop-filter: brightness(0.2)` или другие эффекты, их комбинации).
Проблема в том, что при наложении этих `div` друг на друга их эффект удваивается, видно место их пересечения. Как избавиться от этого эффекта?

Перестать накладывать их друг на друга я не могу в силу ряда причин. Хочется обойтись CSS-свойствами.

На картинке я отметил стрелками нежелательный эффект. Полупрозрачные `div` расположены вертикально, места их пересечений видны как вертикальные линии.

Я пробовал различные `mix-blend-mode` в комбинации с различными фильтрами и полупрозрачными цветам и всегда получал эффект при наложении блоков.

Сами полупрозрачные блоки рисуются в абсолютных позициях и не всегда друг за другом, по этому использование псевдоэлементов не подходит для точного позиционирования блоков.

[image: пример нежелательного эффекта наложения]

Код:

```
<div class="wall" style="left: 170px; width:85px;"></div>
<div class="wall" style="left: 254px; width:283px;"></div>
<div class="wall" style="left: 537px; width:8px;"></div>

.wall {
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    backdrop-filter: brightness(0.9);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, ваш код

Comment: Дополнил текст вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что если все блоки сделать без прозрачности, но сунуть в контейнер и сделать полупрозрачным его

Comment: Отличное решение, подходит! Спасибо!